# I'm being asked to update to a NON-LTS version of Ubuntu

Tags: updates

Now and then when updates happen I am seeing a request to update to 20.10.  I am using 20.04.

I searched around and found a way to do it.

But I am not sure I understand what is being said.

I took a screen shot only because it covers the next question also.

If you also look at the top (address bar of the browser) you can see the question that was asked about preventing updates to non LTS versions.

[image: what the web page said to do and what I have as/in the settings]

So there are THREE options:
NEVER
NORMAL
LTS

So the web site says to put it to `never`.   But I am reading that as it will never check for updates.

That can be problematic if there are security updates (or what ever)

`normal` is what I would suspect to be a problem if I was using a non-LTS version.

But mine is set to LTS.

So why am I getting these requesters to update to 20.10?

Comment: You have correct `Prompt=lts` value in conifiguration file. I would recommend to wait for 2022.April (or better May) and upgrade to 22.04 LTS. Having unnecessary non-LTS upgrades is time-consuming.

Comment: If your system is Ubuntu, correctly updated & not modified in unauthorized ways; you will **not** be offered to upgrade to 20.10; as upgrades are only offered to *supported* release of Ubuntu; and [20.10 is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/) so upgrades to it are **not** possible on a correctly setup Ubuntu system.   I'd check your facts & something is definitely wrong if you're offered an upgrade to 20.10 - it hasn't been offered since 22-July-2021 on correctly setup & upgraded systems.

Comment: Check for addition of Pop OS packages (eg. have you added PopOS or other non-Ubuntu sources & packages & converted your system into a partial PopOS/etc system). Systems based on Ubuntu allow upgrades after Ubuntu turns them off, and this maybe a symptom of changes you've made that have turned your once Ubuntu system into a *frakensystem*.  Read the `sudo apt update` looking for clues I'm suggesting.  (*I'm using PopOS as example; it's not the only Ubuntu-based that does it*)

Comment: I haven't got any POP OS stuff installed AFAIK.
I have a couple of _foreign_ things, but not major.
And (typical) now I say that, I can't for the life of me remember what they are.

Comment: As already stated; Ubuntu releases won't allow upgrade to an EOL release meaning it's not a Ubuntu tool that is allowing the upgrade; Pop OS (used as example) allows for this having different dates to Ubuntu (as based on Ubuntu; they release/EOL later..) so either you're asking about events before 22-July-2021 (ie. EOL) or not a using Ubuntu system (possible you've not applied some updates thus packages don't have 22-July-2021 date encoded; more likely though non-Ubuntu dates are there) as Ubuntu 20.10 is EOL & Ubuntu systems will **not** offer/allow upgrade to it  (Ubuntu would offer 21.04)